# What is wrong with my javascript recursion loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, recursion

This is a code I am writing for leetcode question 46. I implemented the same logic in Python and it worked, but when I tried to write a JS equivalent of it, it doesn't work as expected. The for loops are not running for some reason.

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @return {number[][]}
 */
const permute = nums => {

    const final_list = [];
    
    const bfs = (num, new_nums, current_list) => {
        current_list.push(num);
        if(new_nums.length === 0){
            final_list.push(current_list);
            return;
        }
        // This loop does not run for all iterations
        for(i=0;i<new_nums.length;i++){
            let new_nums2 = new_nums.filter(n => n!== new_nums[i]);
            bfs(new_nums[i], [...new_nums2], [...current_list]);
        }
    }
    // Only the runs for i=0    
    for(i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
        let new_nums = nums.filter(n => n!== nums[i]);
        bfs(nums[i], new_nums, []);
    }
    
    return final_list  
};
```

Input: [1,2,3]
Output: [[1,2,3]]

I know the problem is with the loops because I console logged the loops and it does not fully run. In the bottom loop for example, it only ran for i=0. What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit**: Thanks to @Bergi I found out what's wrong, I missed the declaration for I. I don't think the flagged duplicate question is very helpful here though, just by looking at the so-called duplicate question I would never have known where I went wrong.

Comment: You forgot to declare `i`, creating a global variable shared by all your loops. Use strict mode!

Comment: Damn I'm dumb. Thanks @Bergi!